# unable to load the GetMyMessagesRequestType class when calling the namespace

Tags: php, symfony, php-7, ebay-api

I am unable to load the GetMyMessagesRequestType class from the ebay-sdk which is in the following namespace :

```
 use DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Services;
 use DTS\ebaySDK\Trading\Types;
```

when i call the following:

```
    use DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Services;
    use DTS\ebaySDK\Shopping\Types;
```

the class in question which ebayTime loads perfectly :

```
 $service = new Services\ShoppingService();

  // Create the request object.
  $request = new Types\GeteBayTimeRequestType();

  // Send the request to the service operation.
  $response = $service->geteBayTime($request);

  // Output the result of calling the service operation.
  printf("The official eBay time is: %s\n", $response->Timestamp->format('H:i (\G\M\T) \o\n l jS Y'));
```

this code works.

but the code i have changed now looks like this :

```
   $service = new Services\TradingService([
    'authToken'=> "",
    'credentials' => [
      'appId' => '',
      'certId' => '',
      'devId' => ''
    ],
    'siteId'=>0
  ]);



  $request = new Types\GetMyMessagesRequestType();
```

and i get the following error message :

```
 Attempted to load class "GetMyMessagesRequestType" from namespace "DTS\ebaySDK\Trading\Types".
  Did you forget a "use" statement for "DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Types\GetMyMessagesRequestType"
```

any ideas this is one little thing i am unable to fix to complete the project?

Answer (score 0):

When you changed the use statements to `DTS\ebaySDK\Shopping\Types`, the class you're trying to instantiate is looking in the wrong namespace: `DTS\ebaySDK\Shopping\Types\GetMyMessagesRequestType` does not exist.

1. Either change the offending line from:

   ```
   $request = new Types\GetMyMessagesRequestType();
   ```

   into (note the leading backslash):

   ```
   $request = new \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Types\GetMyMessagesRequestType();
   ```
2. Or add a use statement to the correct namespace:

   ```
   use DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Types\GetMyMessagesRequestType;

   $request = new GetMyMessagesRequestType();
   ```